# Rails-like escaping javascript with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I'm trying to write the equivalent of Rails escape_javascript() in php with a preg_match()
Is there any php built in function ?
Can someone help ?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb, line 50
def escape_javascript(javascript)
  if javascript
    javascript.gsub(/(\\|<\/|\r\n|[\n\r"'])/) { JS_ESCAPE_MAP[$1] }
  else
  ''
  end
end
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode)

I can't say that it's a one-to-one match, but it's a straightforward way to escape JavaScript values in PHP.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks ;) Never saw the options that talke json_encode(): JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_AMP